# Unity lighting not working right in scene view

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

Ive spent a really long time trying to figure out what the issue with my lighting is. When hitting play at the top of the screen im able to see all lighitng totatly fine no matter if its set on real time mixed or baked, or if its set on directional, point or spot. But in scene view for some reason im not able to see any lights there is one exeption though. With directional lighting it works in both cases (scene or play) but for some reason when hitting play and then going into game camera its got an insane amount of blur and this only happens for directional camera. This I think is a seprate problem but its still anoyying they dont look the same so if you could find out an answer for that as well that would be great.

[scene view directional with play button hit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g527q.png)
[game view directional with play button hit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2GkK.png)

[Scene view point lighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU3Bl.jpg)
[Scene view point lighting after play button hit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbDRf.jpg)

I've tried toggeling scene lighting messing around with bake settings my intensity and range are in the thousands.
if you need any extra information to diagnos please ask as I am completly at a loss here

I tried messing around with scene lighting settings, enviroment settings, scene lighting or enviroment lighting toggle and a few other things. Nothing has worked and im at a complete loss please help

Comment: try this https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/